# How to debug a Hard Error coming from a Journey Builder Custom Activity in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

Dears, we are trying to implement a Custom Activity in Journey Builder in Marketing Cloud.

It works perfectly in our test BU but creates a Hard Error on production BU.

The logs of the app behind the Custom Activity (Azure server) return no error whatsoever and all the data is processed correctly, but Marketing Cloud returns "Internal Server Error" when the data gets back from the app.

Has anyone ever encountered this kind of issue before? Here is a piece of data retrieved from Journey History, it doesn't say much: Any help or ideas are highly appreciated

```
{
    "id": "123456789",
    "longId": 123456789,
    "mid": 123456789,
    "eventId": "S0M3-GU1D-K3Y-G03SR1G4T-H3R3",
    "definitionId": "S0M3-GU1D-K3Y-G03SR1G4T-H3R3",
    "definitionName": "My Journey",
    "eventName": "My Journey",
    "contactKey": "S0M3-K3Y-G03SR1G4T-H3R3",
    "entrySource": "Kafka",
    "epochTimeInMilliseconds": 1705970002005,
    "transactionTime": "2024-01-23T00:33:22.005Z",
    "status": "Failed",
    "clientStatus": "Error",
    "message": "",
    "activityId": "S0M3-GU1D-K3Y-G03SR1G4T-H3R3",
    "activityType": "RESTDECISION",
    "activityName": "",
    "definitionInstanceId": "S0M3-GU1D-K3Y-G03SR1G4T-H3R3",
    "createdDate": "2024-01-22T18:33:22.005-06:00",
    "activityBatchInstanceId": "S0M3-GU1D-K3Y-G03SR1G4T-H3R3",
    "eid": 123456789,
    "startDate": "2024-01-22T18:33:20.864-06:00",
    "endDate": "2024-01-22T18:33:22.005-06:00",
    "sourceType": 0,
    "result": {
        "status": "Fail",
        "outcome": {},
        "tags": [],
        "messages": [
            {
                "level": "Error",
                "errorCode": "JourneyBuilder_InternalError",
                "message": "Internal Server Error",
                "type": "Unexpected"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_score": 0.0,
    "messageSource": 1
}
```

Comment: Not sure about Azure but Amazon log group returns the message but you have to fetch it for the Custom Activity